# things to learn for flutter app development

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter, I have picked flutter for app development, I am new to just started a few weeks ago, I wanted to ask if someone could guide me on what are the things that I need to learn to make apps that are fast, robust and useful.
please do mention resources from where I can learn flutter too.

Would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. So, great to hear that.

The most important thing you would have to learn and with which you can make any app, its **Firebase**.

If you are new to it, you may think of it as a **Development Kit** Packed with many features, like User-Auth, Data-Handling, Storing content on the Cloud, and much more.

**Here's a use case -**
You want to make a Social Media App and want users to share posts among themselves. How would you send a message from one device to the other, or notify all his friends when we posts?

Firebase comes in here. You can upload his message to the database (like a hard disk anyone can access from anywhere) and the other users can download it.

You can learn about firebase [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5J5ho7YUhA).

To see its usage with flutter, you can see [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/).

I think it's **the only must skill** needed to make apps after you've learned the basics of Flutter.

Answer (score 2):

try this blogs it helps a lot,

Also learn `Provider or mobx flutter` like state management,think provider is easy to learn but it's up to you check above answers for more insight

[Resocoder](https://resocoder.com)

[FilledStack](https://www.filledstacks.com)

[Github link for flutter tutorial](https://github.com/iampawan/FlutterExampleApps)

[flutter-layouts-walkthrough-row-column-stack-expanded-padding](https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-layouts-walkthrough-row-column-stack-expanded-padding-5ed64e8f9584)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend also looking into [State management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) having a good understanding of this concept will allow you to code more robust apps and faster.

Take a look at third party libraries for state management like:

- [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)
- [Redux](https://pub.dev/packages/redux)
- [MobX](https://pub.dev/packages/mobx)
- etc...